# what's gem can operate Excel on linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, win32ole

My users will update their Excel to my system and I will get some information from it, I know the gem that named "win32OLE" on windows is run well, but my system is ubuntu, so how can I operate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ruby Spreadsheet gem will work for you https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [roo](https://rubygems.org/gems/roo) and [parseescel](https://rubygems.org/gems/parseexcel)as well.